# Java chat - connection just on request

Tags: java, sockets, client-server

I just programmed a Java Server-Client Chat (with multiple clients) where they log in, chat and log out. The socket is always started and I listen in a loop.

Now I have to program this kind of chat where the connection isn't always open, so the the connection just stars "on request" (when someone sends a message).

How do I do this? Could you give me some keywords which I should google?

Comment: once the chat has started (i.e after first request), do you expect the socket to stay open?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a Server and Client that does not have a Open Connection (Correct me If I am wrong) you will have to Open and close the connection manually. As these "connections" represent Streams across the network.

Another Option you can consider is maybe using [UDP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Datagram_Protocol), but this does not close and open a connection on request it only removes the overhead of TCP and it's reliability features.

From the [Datagram Lesson](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/datagrams/index.html) on Oracle.com:

> Some applications that you write to
>   communicate over the network will not
>   require the reliable, point-to-point
>   channel provided by TCP. Rather, your
>   applications might benefit from a mode
>   of communication that delivers
>   independent packages of information
>   whose arrival and order of arrival are
>   not guaranteed.